# Cannot import Swift Code into Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have the project CP Patient :

[image]

I have follow and authorize module :

[image]

When i import swift into my Obj-C i have this error :

[image]

What i have missed?

Comment: I believe that space will be changed to something else, maybe a `_` or `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the space in the Project name will get replaced by an underscore:

```
#import "CP_Patient-Swift.h"
```

I would recommend not to use Project/Framework names with spaces or special characters.

You might ask why this happens. The reason is simple. All your Swift code is automatically wrapped into a *Swift module*. The name of the module is the name of your project. However, there are rules for module naming. Normally modules are imported like this:

```
@import Foundation
```

So, obviously, we can't have spaces in module names. In general a module name has to be a valid *identifier*. All invalid characters (e.g. a number in the beginning) will be replaced with an underscore.

The Obj-C import does not import a file, it imports a Swift module.